# Deployment/Distribution/Installation of Apache modules

Tags: apache, deployment, installation, module

I am a student and on an internship currently. I was developing an Apache module, that will be available for my company's clients to download and use.

I have completed the module now. Now I want to know what are the best practices regarding the deployment of module.

Should I provide binaries of the module or source files ? What can I assume about the technical competence of the webmasters who usually maintain the servers ?

Additionally the biggest problem that I see is that different OS distros usually mess with the Apache directory structure, so it is very difficult to even provide a standard guide that will help user's to install the module.

Does anyone has had experience with this kind of a situation ? What are the usual practices of software distribution/deployment/installation ?